# How to add type definition before parsing a class?

Tags: powershell, class, type-definition

I have A Powershell code that includes a TypeDefinition and a custom class like below sample. This throws an error, when I want to execute that code, because the PS-parser checks the class before the TypeDefinition. If I manually execute only the TypeDefinition and run the full code after that, then all works as expected.

How can I change the code in that way, that it will run in one go?

```
add-type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
public static class MeaningOf {
    public const Int32 Life = 42;
}
"@

class Planet {
    [void] earth() {
        $result = [MeaningOf]::Life
    }
}
```

Comment: In short: You're trying to use `Add-Type`-added .NET types in the context of a PowerShell custom [class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes) defined in the same file. Unfortunately, this isn't supported as of this writing, because any .NET types referenced in `class` definitions must have been loaded _beforehand_. See the linked duplicate for workarounds and potential future improvements.

Comment: Assuming the code is in a file, can I load the .NET types from the same file and then continue? I dont see a solution here for the Invoke-Expression workaround.

Comment: You can make your code work by wrapping the _PowerShell_ `class` definition in a string you can pass to `Invoke-Expression`

Comment: Best short answer to this topic ever!